# CryptoJS with Bower, how to manage this dependency?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, bower, cryptojs

I need to manage [CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) with Bower. This project is hosted on code.google.com. Can be downloaded as [zip file](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/downloads/list) or through the [SVN](http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags).

Can Bower download an uncompress the zip file or download all components from the SVN and put them in the `crypto` folder?

`.bowerrc` file, defining the download folder:

```
{
  "directory": "app/vendor"
}
```

I've tried this `component.json` file (fails, downloads the page itself):

```
{
  "name": "Backbone Client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
     "crypto": "http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/"
  }
}
```

Another try (`hmac.js` overriders `core.js` and it's saved as `index.js`):

```
{
  "name": "Backbone Client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto":
       "http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/core.js",
    "crypto":
       "http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/hmac.js"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the way reading [Bower official page](http://twitter.github.com/bower/):

> As you can see, packages can be installed by name, Git endpoint,
>   GitHub shorthand, URL or local path. If you install from a URL that
>   points to a zip or tar file, bower will automatically extract its
>   contents.

`component.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Backbone Client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/CryptoJS%20v3.1.2.zip"
  }
}
```

Comment: The link is down. Can you please update the url to: https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS/archive/v3.1.2.zip

The author promises to have uploaded the original code.